# sort a list by prefered order

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

is it possible to sort through a list and do something depending on your preferred order or pre determined choice?

so i have a list of files containing definitions, if i re.search the string and return a match, i would like to only print the string + highest definition

i started to explore the below idea but i cannot seem to get it to print only the highest -currently it prints all 3

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re
definitions = ['1080p', '720p', 'SD'] # order (highest to lowest)
some_files = ['movie_a_1080p.mp4', 'movie_b_720p.mp4','movie_c_SD.mp4'] 

for each in some_files:
    for defs in definitions:
        match = re.search(defs, each, re.M | re.I)
        if match:
            if match.group() == '1080p':
                print('1080p', each)
                break
            else:
                if match.group() == '720p':
                    print('720p', each)
                    break
                else:
                if match.group() == 'SD':
                    print('SD', each)
                    break
```

any help would be awesome

Comment: fyi: replace `else: if:` with `elif:`

Comment: What output are you hoping to get? (I can't figure out what you're trying to do.)

Comment: You can define a custom sort function that sorts a list of items using whatever criteria you like.

Comment: [Sorting How To](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sorting-how-to).  max() and min() also take key function arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, this should work:

```
def best(some_files):
    for definition in ('1080p', '720p', 'SD'):
        match = next((file for file in some_files if definition in file), None)
        if match is not None:
            return match

print(best(['movie_a_1080p.mp4', 'movie_b_720p.mp4', 'movie_c_SD.mp4']))  # movie_a_1080p.mp4
print(best(['movie_b_720p.mp4', 'movie_c_SD.mp4', 'movie_a_1080p.mp4']))  # movie_a_1080p.mp4
print(best(['movie_b_720p.mp4', 'movie_c_SD.mp4']))  # movie_b_720p.mp4
print(best(['movie_d.mp4', 'movie_c_SD.mp4']))  # movie_c_SD.mp4
print(best(['movie_d.mp4']))  # None
```

The main issue with your approach is that the `break` only breaks out of the nearest loop. @alfasin's answer fixes this by `return`ing from a function instead.

My answer could also just be used without a function if you want, since it only has one loop to break out of:

```
for definition in ('1080p', '720p', 'SD'):
    match = next((file for file in some_files if definition in file), None)
    if match is not None:
        print('Found the best one: {}'.format(match))
        break
```

Comment: this is perfect, EXACTLY what i had in mind, so in essence you can use `return` to "break" out from deep within statements? i was wondering if my issue was due to not breaking out properly.

Comment: Well, `return` will return from the enclosing function. So yes, you can use `return` to do that, but only if you're inside a function.

Answer (score 2):

Since your `definitions` is in order, you can just traverse the lists, and return the file when a match is found.

```
def best_quality(l):
    definitions = ['1080p', '720p', 'SD'] # order (highest to lowest)
    for definition in definitions:
        for file in some_files:
            if definition in file: return file

some_files = ['movie_c_SD.mp4', 'movie_a_1080p.mp4', 'movie_b_720p.mp4']
print best_quality(some_files)
>>> movie_a_1080p.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only a single result (the highest) and considering that your list is ordered highest to lowest, you can simply return after the first result was found:

```
import re
definitions = ['1080p', '720p', 'SD'] # order (highest to lowest)
some_files = ['movie_a_1080p.mp4', 'movie_b_720p.mp4', 'movie_c_SD.mp4']

def find():
    for each in some_files:
        for defs in definitions:
            match = re.search(defs, each, re.M | re.I)
            if match:
                return match.group(0)


print(find())
```